# Is there a reference option when using fisher exact test using proc freq?

Tags: sas

trtpn below has three levels (1 2 3) and i want to perform exact test comparing each (1, 2) treatment group versus placebo (3) group:

```
proc freq data = expect;
    table trtpn*resp / fisher exact  riskdiff(cl=wald) alpha=0.025;
    by avisit;
    weight count;
run;`
```

I tried above codes and it does not provide what I am expecting.

Comment: There is no reference option in `proc freq`. The simplest way is using where statement to subset input dataset.